# Compatible error with russian acoustic model pocketsphinx in android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am doing an app that control an app and give some voice command by using speech recognition and I used pocketsphinx for an android. Firs of all, I just read all of the guidelines from official website of sourceforge.Then I downloaded russian acoustic model which is provided by official sourceforge website and I integrated into my project.

[image: screenshot]

I want that when you lost your phone at your home, I
want that by giving any russian words or maybe it would be person's
name like "максим" as a input data. After that the phone gives alert
when it matches after listening. So my problem is I set russian
dictionary which is downloaded from sourceforge.net but I don't know
how to use it inside the code with digits.gram file together. But I am getting errors like the dictionary is not compatible.

> ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 485423: Phone 'hh' is mising in the
>   acoustic model; word 'хит' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line
>   485451: Phone 'hh' is mising in the acoustic model; word 'хитиновых'
>   ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 485492: Phone 'hh' is mising
>   in the acoustic model; word 'хитрили' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line
>   195: Line 485544: Phone 'hh' is mising in the acoustic model; word
>   'хитроу' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 485589: Phone 'hh' is
>   mising in the acoustic model; word 'хитрющими' ignored ERROR:
>   "dict.c", line 195: Line 485622: Phone 'hh' is mising in the acoustic
>   model; word 'хихикнул' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 485663:
>   Phone 'hh' is mising in the acoustic model; word 'хищническим' ignored
>   ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 485664: Phone 'hh' is mising in the
>   acoustic model; word 'хищнических' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195:
>   Line 485696: Phone 'aa' is mising in the acoustic model; word
>   'хладное' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 485711: Phone 'ay'
>   is mising in the acoustic model; word 'хладнокровной' ignored ERROR:
>   "dict.c", line 195: Line 485759: Phone 'll' is mising in the acoustic
>   model; word 'хлебала' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 485796:
>   Phone 'll' is mising in the acoustic model; word 'хлебнувшие' ignored
>   ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 485868: Phone 'll' is mising in the
>   acoustic model; word 'хлебъ' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line
>   485892: Phone 'll' is mising in the acoustic model; word 'хлестала'
>   ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 485943: Phone 'll' is mising
>   in the acoustic model; word 'хлипкими' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line
>   195: Line 485995: Phone 'oo' is mising in the acoustic model; word
>   'хлопец' ignored ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 486037: Phone 'oo' is
>   mising in the acoustic model; word 'хлопнулся' ignored

I just googled about it but nothing found. What should I do now? Any suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions?